# string to char array c# results in error

Tags: c#, arrays, string

Basically I'm making a hangman game in C# but the problem is whenever I try to turn my `string` word to `char[]` with `word.ToCharArray();` it does not work.

Can someone figure out what is wrong with this code?

```
List<string> words = new List<string>();
List<string> guessedLetters = new List<string>();
string word = "sword";

// Turning word into char array
char[] letters = word.ToCharArray();
```

> CS0236  A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'Form1.word'   final C:\Users*\Desktop\final\final\Form1.cs   20  Active

Comment: Looks like you're doing this outside of a method body against instance fields. If this is what you mean to do, put the initialization of `letters` in the constructor, or define a proper method for your code.

Comment: Please post your whole code that you are using.

Answer (score 1):

So far what is known, you have a class named `Form1`:

```
public class Form1 {
      List<string> words = new List<string>();
      List<string> guessedLetters = new List<string>();
      string word = "sword";
      //...
      public static void Main(string[]args){
          char[] letters = word.ToCharArray(); 
      }
}
```

If this is the case then, you are doing it wrong. You will need an object of class `Form1` to use variable `word`.

```
      public static void Main(string[]args){
          Form1 F1 = new Form1();
          char[] letters = F1.word.ToCharArray(); 
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have something like this that you can fix with a `static`.
But this is probably not the best design.

```
class Program
{
    List<string> words = new List<string>();
    List<string> guessedLetters = new List<string>();
    static string word = "sword";
    char[] letters = word.ToCharArray();
```

This might be a better design:

```
public List<string> words { get; } = new List<string>();
public List<string> guessedLetters { get; } = new List<string>();
public string word { get; set; } = "sword";
public char[] letters { get { return word.ToCharArray(); } }
```

Answer (score 0):

error says a static field is required under a static method for a call, so change word as static -

```
static string word = "sword";
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can move the initialization into the *constructor*:

```
  public partial class Form1: Form {
    ...
    List<string> words = new List<string>();
    List<string> guessedLetters = new List<string>();
    string word;

    // Turning word into char array
    char[] letters;

    public Form1() {
      word = "sword"; 
      letters = word.ToCharArray();         
    }  
  }
```

Another possibility is to declare property: whenever you want to have `word` split into letters just call `letters` property

```
  public partial class Form1: Form {
    ...
    List<string> words = new List<string>();
    List<string> guessedLetters = new List<string>();
    string word = "sword";

    ...

    private char[] letters {
      get {
        return null == word 
          ? new char[0]
          : word.ToCharArray(); 
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From Microsoft Docs:
["Instance fields cannot be used to initialize other instance fields outside a method."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0236)

Its a compiler decision and that's just the way it is. Or setting a constant with a variable, little things like that are design decisions and there are seasons behind them big or small like a matter of taste.

You can fix it by making `word` a `static` but I don't know if that is what you want.